# Centrifugal Game Engine

Tags: game-physics

I am not entirely sure if this is the correct stack exchange, so if anyone thinks that there is a better place for it, say so in the comments:

Are there any game engines which would allow me to have a space station where illusory gravity is generated through centripetal force?  Normal gravity in an engine such as unity would not work, as there are special physical properties that this rotation method has as side effects.  For example, if you run in one direction, "gravity" will exert less force on you.  A bullet might never actually fall if it is shot at the right speed in the right direction.  The Coriolis effect would mean that falling objects would curve.  I could, of course, actually have a space station rotating in Unity, but this seems like it might make the game CPU bottlenecked.   Any suggestions?

Comment: "but this seems like it might make the game CPU bottlenecked" – why? Do you have any benchmarks / theoretical reasoning to justify this?

Comment: There would be many more operations required per second, as it would have to rediscover the laws of physics in a cylinder each time

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "rediscover", or indeed "it"; you should probably implement this and find out if it is *actually* inefficient.

Comment: I am a complete novice, so that is above my pay grade.  I would imagine that doing standard Newtonian physics for every object and then calculating the vectors of each ones velocity and the forces acting on it would be harder than having a cheat sheet with the way objects move centrifugally already calculated.  Imagine being told to calculate the path of a "falling" object in a cemtrifuge.  Wouldn't it be so much easier if you had just learned that physics in 8th grade, along with how objects on Earth make a very small segment of an elipse, so small it looks like a parabola, when falling.

Comment: No point in making unjustified speculations from your own perspective as a human - computers don't work in the same way. Rotational systems obey **the same** laws of physics as non-rotational ones, and correspondingly they will **not** be more difficult for a well-written general-purpose physic engine to handle. If you don't understand the physics, ask on the Physics SE, but don't assume that the developers of Unity's physics engine didn't either.

Comment: I understand that a centrifuge still obeys the laws of physics, but I merely meant that assuming the centrifuge to be standing still and having new laws of physics might lead to fewer calculations required to render a frame.  If you consider all the objects that will be standing still, from an inertial perspective they would be moving in circles and you would need to do many calculations for each.   If, instead, the engine assumes them to be still, and just has different laws of physics, the game might be more potato-friendly.

Comment: If you do not have an unreasonable number of objects (which Unity is not meant for anyway), any "additional" calculations will pale into insignificance when compared to the amount of processing power required to merely *render* the scene. To re-iterate the key point: no amount of theoretical speculation will beat cold hard benchmark statistics.